# min() of haversine formula, narrow results to 1 closest match for sql update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Working on a project that matches up failed deliveries to brand new deliveries with the closest distance match based on the haversine formula.

Currently my code below gets me a 1-for-1 match on each failed delivery in ROUTEID LIKE '%NDD%' against every new delivery NOT LIKE '%NDD%' (as well as some other folders but those can be ignored)

So 5 deliveries against 5000 stops gets me a list of 25000 possibilities. If I take this to excel and run "remove duplicates", viola, I have the closest match with no duplicates.

How can I avoid going to excel and narrow it down to just the MIN() match? At that point, I want to turn this into an update query that will update the ROUTEID of my failed deliveries to the closest match in my new deliveries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORS.PKID, ORS.Reference1, P.ROUTEID, P.SEQUENCE,
    MIN(round(
       ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-ORS.lat))
     *COS(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
     +SIN(RADIANS(90-ORS.lat))
     *SIN(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
     *COS(RADIANS(ORS.lon-p.longpoint)))
     *3958.756,2)) 
    AS 'DISTANCE_in_mi'

FROM tblOrderRouteStops AS ORS WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN 
     (
         SELECT ORS2.lat AS latpoint, ors2.lon AS longpoint,
             ORS2.Sequence, ORS2.routeid
             from tblOrderRouteStops ORS2 WITH (NOLOCK)
              WHERE ORS2.CUSTID = 180016
              AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%NDD%'
              AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%PND%'
              AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%NFW%'
     ) AS p ON 1=1

WHERE ORS.CustID = 180016
AND ORS.RouteID LIKE '%NDD%'
AND P.RouteID NOT LIKE '%NDD%'
AND P.RouteID NOT LIKE '%PND%'
AND P.RouteID NOT LIKE '%NFW%'

GROUP BY ORS.PKID,ORS.REFERENCE1,P.ROUTEID,P.SEQUENCE

ORDER BY DISTANCE_in_mi
```

Comment: Can you explain issue with current query? Please illustrate with sample data current results and desired results.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Haversine for the distances and not using the geospatial capabilities of SQL Server? I ask because it looks like you're trying to run a 'nearest neighbor' query and that's pretty efficient with spatial indexing.

Comment: Ben you just blew my mind. I am new at this stuff so I didn't realize this was possible. At this point, I need to explore that option because I don't know anything about it. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Parfait I was able to figure out what I needed, I needed a 2nd subquery for routeID. In the original query, I was getting 100% of matches closest through furthest.

Answer (score 0):

The [APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) operator can be used to find the minimal matching row for each row in the outer query.  Something like this:

```
select ORS.PKID, ORS.Reference1, P.ROUTEID, P.SEQUENC, p.DISTANCE_in_mi
FROM tblOrderRouteStops AS ORS 
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT top 1 ORS.PKID, ORS.Reference1, P.ROUTEID, P.SEQUENCE,
        MIN(round(
           ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-ORS.lat))
         *COS(RADIANS(90-p.LAT))
         +SIN(RADIANS(90-ORS.lat))
         *SIN(RADIANS(90-p.LAT))
         *COS(RADIANS(ORS.lon-p.lon)))
         *3958.756,2)) 
        AS DISTANCE_in_mi
     FROM tblOrderRouteStops AS P
     WHERE P.CUSTID = 180016
     AND P.routeID NOT LIKE '%NDD%'
     AND P.routeID NOT LIKE '%PND%'
     AND P.routeID NOT LIKE '%NFW%'
     ORDER BY DISTANCE_in_mi 
) p
WHERE ORS2.CUSTID = 180016
AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%NDD%'
AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%PND%'
AND ORS2.routeID NOT LIKE '%NFW%'
```